# Alarm Manager Notification Issue.?

Tags: android

I am developing an app where i have to pop-up some reminder notification.For this requirement i have developed the code. My Code is working fine. But the problem is when i kill the app(settings->applications->Manage applications->application->force close)it is not firing the events. why it is happening like this is any one is having any idea..??

In android Manifest file I have added:

< receiver android:process=":remote" android:name=".AlarmReceiver" />

Here is my code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NotificationHandler.class);

     // Setup the intent to handle calling our receiver
     PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), RXMIND_TAKE, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

     // This is important because we want to grab the next 15 mintue
     // interval to fire the handler at. We will then set the repeats
     // to 15 minutes for the reoccurnce
     Date interval = Timeer.getFifteenMinuteInterval();      

     // Get the AlarmManager service
     AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Activity.ALARM_SERVICE);

     // Setup the handler then set the repeats to 15min. This will hit exactly on the 15 minute
     // interval for every hour
     am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, interval.getTime(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES, sender);
```